# call to web API from browser not working with Async action

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have created a web API that have the below async action

```
[ActionName("getFedCust")]
    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> getFedCust()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://fw.dev.test.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/api/fed");                
            return response;               

        }
    }
```

my controller name is ADAccount
when I call from Chrome my action using below route browser tell that it cannot found action getFedCust
http://localhost:55074/api/adaccount/getFedCust.

I have let the default route in the WEBapiConfig.cs

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate:"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

by the way if I create a non async action it works

```
    public HttpResponseMessage getFedCust()
{
    FedCust[] fedcust = new FedCust[]
    {
        new FedCust {name="Fabrikam"
            ,domains="fabrikam.local"
            ,sts="http://fabrikam.test.com/adfs/services/trust"
        },
        new FedCust {name="Contoso"
            ,domains="contoso.local"
            ,sts="http://contoso.test.com/adfs/services/trust"
        }
    };
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, fedcust, "application/json");
}
```

any help will be welcomed as I'm quite novice in that part

Comment: Define "not working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think mistakenly you have defined your async action as "private".

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> getFedCust()
```

should be:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> getFedCust()
```